# AWS S3 Signed URL with long validity in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, signed-url

I am trying to implement long validity signed URL for AWS S3 object. Is it possible to set 100 years in per expiration policy object like below.

```
    public string GetPreSignedURL(string bucketName, string identifierName, string fileName)
    {
        var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = this.GetObjectKey(identifierName, fileName),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(100)
        };

        return this.awsS3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
    }
```

If not, kindly provide some reference to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html#PresignedUrl-Expiration):

> Expiration time for presigned URLs
>
> A presigned URL remains valid for the period of time specified when the URL is generated. If you create a presigned URL with the Amazon S3 console, the expiration time can be set between 1 minute and 12 hours. If you use the AWS CLI or AWS SDKs, the expiration time can be set as high as 7 days.
>
> If you created a presigned URL by using a temporary token, then the URL expires when the token expires, even if you created the URL with a later expiration time.

Comment: The key here is that even with long lived credentials like user secret + access key the expiration is limited to 7 days. All other credentials are short lived and can by definition not issue an url that is valid for longer.

Comment: Kindly let me know the other way to achieve long live url

Comment: @user3083835 that is an entirely different question.